# Turning datagrid values to a datatable

Tags: vb.net, datagrid, datatable

I have a datagrid that I want to turn into a datatable on a button click. I had thought the way you convert a grid to a table was below but when I run it I get that the table is null. Have no idea what I am doing wrong.

```
Dim dt = DirectCast(dtgrid.DataSource, DataTable)
```

Comment: how did the data get into the datagrid?

Comment: That's run in another function and some user input. Main point is whats on the grid is what I need in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer. It was that I was not posting the checkbox values back into the dataset.